# How to extract a complete list of extension types within a directory?

Tags: windows-xp, script, shell-script, batch-file, file-extension

Within a directory, and recursively within it's sub-directories, meaning every directory within a directory is processed, how do I compile a complete list of unique extensions within the directory?

OS is Windows XP with all the current updates, but I okay running script if I'm able to tell what it's doing, though I would prefer not to have to install dot-net, since I really do not like it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This batch script will do it.

```
@echo off

set target=%~1
if "%target%"=="" set target=%cd%

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set LF=^


rem Previous two lines deliberately left blank for LF to work.

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "%target%"') do (
    set ext=%%~xi
    if "!ext!"=="" set ext=FileWithNoExtension
    echo !extlist! | find "!ext!:" > nul
    if not !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 set extlist=!extlist!!ext!:
)

echo %extlist::=!LF!%

endlocal
```

Save it as any `.bat` file, and run it with the command `batchfile` (substitute whatever you named it) to list the current directory, or specify a path with `batchfile "path"`. It will search all subdirectories.

If you want to export to a file, use `batchfile >filename.txt` (or `batchfile "path" >filename.txt`).

#### Explanation

Everything before the `for /f...` line just sets things up: it gets the target directory to search, enables [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) which lets me do update variables in the loop and [defines a newline (`LF`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379861/1030702) that I can use for neater output. Oh, and the `%~1` means "get the first argument, removing quotes" which prevents doubled-up quotes - see `for /?`.

The loop uses that `dir /b /s /a:-d "%target%"` command, grabbing a list of all files in all subdirectories under the target.

`%%~xi` extracts the extension out of the full paths the `dir` command returns.

An empty extension is replaced with "FileWithNoExtension", so you know there is such a file - if I added an empty line instead, it's not quite as obvious.

The whole current list if sent through a `find` command, to ensure uniqueness. The text output of the find command is sent to `nul`, essentially a black hole - we don't want it. Since we always append a `:` at the end of the list, we should also make sure the search query ends with a `:` so it doesn't match partial results - see comments.

%ERRORLEVEL% is set by the `find` command, a value of 0 indicates there was a match. So if it's not 0, the current extension is not on the list so far and should be added.

The echo line basically outputs, and I also replace my placeholders (`:`) with newlines to make it look nice.

Comment: +1 @Bob: Amazing answer, adding the explanation was a huge help too. Just tested the script, reviewed the results of the test, and everything worked great. Again, thanks!

Comment: It worked PERFECTLY! I used the following syntax: `batchfile "path" >filename.txt`

Comment: Great script!  But there is a small bug with it : if the folder contain files `aaa.css` and `zzz.cs`, extension `.cs` will not be reported by the script.

Comment: @Goozak Whoops. Fixed now. The wonders of text searching... had to make sure the search query ended with `:` to force it to match boundaries.

Answer (score 38):

Although not strictly meeting the requirement for a batch script, I have used a single-line piped `PowerShell` script:

```
Get-Childitem C:\MyDirectory -Recurse -File | Group Extension -NoElement | Sort Count -Desc > FileExtensions.txt
```

Where:

1. `Get-ChildItem C:\MyDirectory -Recurse` retrieves all files in the directory and subdirectories.
2. `Group Extension -NoElement` groups the results by the file extension.
3. `Sort Count -Desc` Sorts the results by the number of matching extensions in each group (from most to least).
4. `> FileExtensions.txt` pipes the results to the specified file.

You could potentially run it from the command line/batch file:

```
Powershell -Command "& Get-Childitem C:\MyDirectory -Recurse -File | Group Extension -NoElement | Sort Count -Desc > FileExtensions.txt"
```

If you remove `C:\MyDirectory` it will execute in the current directory.

**Edit 2021-04-20:** As per the comment from @ManSamVampire, if you want to find hidden files as well, you should add `-Force` before `-Recurse` in the above command.

At the end it will produce a FileExtensions.txt containing something like the following:

```
+-------+------+
| Count | Name |
+-------+------+
| ----- | ---- |
| 8216  | .xml |
| 4854  | .png |
| 4378  | .dll |
| 3565  | .htm |
| ...   | ...  |
+-------+------+
```

Depending on your folder structure, you may occasionally get errors notifying you that you have a long path.

```
Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Any subdirectories in there will also not be parsed but the results for everything else will still show.

> ## Notes
>
> You will of course need PowerShell which you can grab from [here](https://github.com/powershell/powershell#get-powershell). It can also run on multiple operating systems.

Comment: Thanks, agree that it's a useful answer. On an unrelated note, bit puzzled how you've posted only single answer, yet have the "Fanatic" badge for visiting Superuser for 100 consecutive days. Do you have the site bookmarked or something?

Comment: The badge was awarded in 2010 when I effectively lurked, but I'm *far* more active on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/users/31532/dan-atkinson. :)

Comment: This is great. Though, I also had to add the `-Force` parameter to the `Get-ChildItem` command, to include hidden files as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a detailed answer using PowerShell (with Windows XP you'll have to install PowerShell):

[Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Use Windows PowerShell to Pick Out the Unique File Extensions Used in a Collection of Files?](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/05/10/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-pick-out-the-unique-file-extensions-used-in-a-collection-of-files/)

Comment: While PowerShell is definitely much easier than the command line, it is based on .NET. Which, unfortunately, goes against "I would prefer not to have to install dot-net".

Comment: +1 @RichardM: Agree with Bob. Also, the code related to the counting of extension instances found -- not knowing anything about PowerShell -- appears very memory heavy; meaning instead of just keeping a count of every instance, it's I believe creating an array to store duplicate instances of an extension for each extension, then doing a count for each extension array at the end, which to me seems like a very odd way of counting extension instances. Am I missing something? (That said, the first PowerShell one-liner is nice, and I'd try it if I didn't dislike dotnet.)

Comment: That's fair. This question may draw searchers who are more open to a PowerShell solution. Mind you, a decent Google search will find the above link as well.

Comment: +1 for this link. blunders obvious dislikes everything .net, but that doesn't mean that the solution above is the best *long term* solution to this problem. The more languages the better i think.

Comment: Here's another link that addresses recursive search, using powershell. http://robertbigec.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/determining-unique-file-extensions-recursively-using-powershell/

Answer (score 3):

To list all unique extensions from cmd under the path your on use:

```
Powershell -Command "Get-ChildItem . -Include *.* -Recurse | Select-Object Extension | Sort-Object -Property Extension -Unique"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it useful to change

```
if "!ext!"=="" set ext=FileWithNoExtension
```

to

```
if "!ext!"=="" set ext=.FileWithNoExtension
```

and to change

```
echo %extlist::=!LF!%
```

to

```
echo %extlist::=!LF!% > ext-list.txt
```

The generated file contained (no linefeeds, but no matter)
.bat.pdf.skp.ai.png.jpg.tif.pcp.txt.lst.ttf.dfont.psd.indd.docx.PDF.JPG.gif.jpeg.dwg.exr.FileWithNoExtension.vrlmap.sat.bak.ctb

which I was then able to use for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I use git bash an just run this one liner

```
find . -type f | sed -e 's/.*\.//' | sed -e 's/.*\///' | sort -u
```