# How to view only unique file extension names under one folder?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract a complete list of extension types within a directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/397943/how-to-extract-a-complete-list-of-extension-types-within-a-directory)

Suppose there are three files, a.txt b.txt c.exe under folder c:\dir\, is there any command that I could get the two file extensions names .txt and .exe.

Comment: Just remove the `/s` in `dir /b /s /a:-d "%target%"` in [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/397943/how-to-extract-a-complete-list-of-extension-types-within-a-directory/397959#397959) to exclude subdirectories.

Comment: A solution for powershell is here: http://superuser.com/a/397961/26503

Comment: This should work: dir /a-d /b | sed -e "s/^.*\([.][^.]*\)/\1/g" | sort | uniq

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking. I think you want to know a DOS command to list all files with a filename extension ending in both .txt and .exe? For that I'd just type in "`DIR C:\DIR\*.EXE; C:\DIR\*.TXT`" (Notice the space after "DIR" and a space after the semicolon. Also don't include the quotes.)

Comment: No. The body of the question is confusing, but the title is more clear. They wanted to query a directory and get a list of unique file extensions based on the files present.